# web application testing framework suggestions

Tags: performance, stress-testing, distributed-system

Anyone have good experience with a web application testing framework? We are in process of selecting one for our application written in C#, ASP.NET etc., but the framework can be anything (unless, of course, choosing one written in C# helps somehow).

The application is distributed. What we would like (ideally) is:

1. Something that will scale from testing individual components (~unit tests), to incrementally larger parts, to the whole system.
2. Something that will collect time stamped logs, measurements etc. and help zoom in on problems as they occur.
3. Easily scriptable by developers of varying skill levels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the web testing framework in Visual Studio itself. That does a lot of what you need and sits right in your development environment. You also have the addition of load testing as well. 
While web tests do not test javascript, they will make sure that each page works correctly.